# Assembly reference in silverlight pages for Asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

i really fedup with this problem.i created a silverlight pages in .net 4.0 framework.now i want to add these page in my Asp.net web application which in framework 3.5 . i getting lots of error for Reference.

like

> Assembly 'System.Windows.Controls.Navigation' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference. Also, verify that your project and all referenced assemblies have been built.
>
> Project file must include the .NET Framework assembly 'WindowsBase, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework' in the reference list.
>
> The type 'HyperlinkButton' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built

please bear me i am new to this thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the references of your original pages are in .net 4 and you are adding these pages in .net 3.5. please renew your references for .net 3.5 and it should work fine.

let me know if this helps you

Comment: can u explain urself. why this is giving error in hyperlink silverlight control

Comment: what version of silverlight are you using with your .net 4 application?

Comment: if you have silverlight 2 in your .net 3.5 application, then it does not support the navigation control. You will need to upgrade the silverlight version to 3.0.